Pandas filtering yields null values
I have a df which I am filtering based on a particular column. This is my code to do that
test_table[(test_table['Item']=='1')]

Ideally this code should return the rows where the value of column 'Item' is equal to '1'. Instead it returns the full dataframe with just that particular row with Item = '1' and all other cells with Nan values. What could be the issue in my code? Why are all the other columns/cells becoming Nan?
The output that I got: (I've hidden the column names)

Can someone help me resolve this?

Please add data to reproduce test_table and the issue.

Check if item column dtype  is an object or integer. If integer the filtering should be changed to == 1

Your code as shown is correct. The problem is not reproducible. Even if the condition is not met that would only produce an empty DF not change to NaNs. You need to provide a [MRE] showing the problem.
